# Getting least norm solution

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Noob question -- how should I get least norm solution in Mathematica for an under-constrained problem? Matrix is not full rank.

I *could* use pseudo-inverse, but inverting a matrix to get a single solution seems like an overkill, is there a more efficient approach?

`ones = {{1, 1}};
H = Transpose[ones].ones;
ones.PseudoInverse[H] (* gives 1/2, 1/2 *)
LinearSolve[H, {1, 1}] (* gives 1, 0 *)`

[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/yaroslavvb/newton/ill-conditioned.nb)

Comment: Try `LeastSquares`.

Comment: SVD ought to work here too, if you're concerned about saving factorization effort.

Comment: @J.M. I doubt that `SingularValueDecomposition` will be faster than `LeastSquares`...

Comment: @Henrik: a test would be needed to be sure, but computing the SVD once, and taking the pseudoinverse of the diagonal factor would be the only precomputation needed. Unless `LeastSquares[]` actually stores a factorization internally instead of computing it for each right-hand-side...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a low rank factorization for your actual matrix, you can speed this up by using `PseudoInverse`, `SingularValueDecomposition`, or `LeastSquares` on the low rank factor `A`. Here a model problem:

```
n = 3000;
m = 300;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];
H = Transpose[A].A;
```

Applying all proposed solutions to the matrix `H`:

```
x1 = LeastSquares[H, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
x2 = PseudoInverse[H].b; // AbsoluteTiming // First
x3 = Module[{U, Σ, V},
     {U, Σ, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[H];
     U.LeastSquares[SparseArray[Σ], b.V]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[x1 - x2]]
Max[Abs[x1 - x3]]
```

> 3.79227
>
> 5.75832
>
> 6.10518
>
> 6.72036*10^-18
>
> 6.31378*10^-18

So, for a single solve, `LeastSquares` performs best. For multiple solves, `PseudoInverse` may be the better choice because it can be reused multiple times.

Now, exploiting the low rank factorization:

```
y1 = LeastSquares[A, LeastSquares[Transpose[A], b]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
y2 = With[{P = PseudoInverse[A]}, P.(b.P)]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
y3 = Module[{U, Σ, V},
     {U, Σ, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
     V.LeastSquares[Transpose[#].# &@SparseArray[Σ], b.V]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[x1 - y1]]
Max[Abs[x1 - y2]]
Max[Abs[x1 - y3]]
```

> 0.069174
>
> 0.057212
>
> 0.37002
>
> 1.04626*10^-17
>
> 6.23416*10^-18
>
> 7.01852*10^-18

Bang! Same accuracy but almost two orders of magnitude faster (best in the second run compared to best in first run). Needless to say that the speed-up get better the smaller the the row count of `A` is.

If you know a priorily that `A` has full rank (and accuracy is not your major concern), then you can also use the following:

```
z1 = With[{S = LinearSolve[A.Transpose[A], Method -> "Cholesky"]},
    S[S[A.b]].A
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[z1 - x1]]
```

> 0.013487
>
> 7.94178*10^-18

*However, this employs the infamous normal equations and if `A` badly conditioned, this can lead to severe errors.*

PS.: No, `LeastSquares` is not the bottleneck in the applications of `SingularValueDecomposition` though it can be optimized away by ``inverting'' the diagonal of `Σ` by hand.

Comment: Nicely done. Just as a note for everybody else: you can manually get the Moore-Penrose inverse of a singular diagonal matrix by inverting all the nonzero diagonal elements and leaving the zero ones untouched. In the inexact arithmetic case, one has to decide on how big a diagonal element must be before one takes its reciprocal, which is efffectively how one decides numerical rank.

Comment: For the normal equations approach, one can do `LinearSolve[A.Transpose[A], Method -> "Cholesky"]` to exploit the SPD structure of the problem.